# What is the best way to combine n correlation factors to predict an outcome?

Tags: time-series, probability, correlation

Let's say that I have **n+1** time series of two outcomes : either **+** or **-**. Time series **A1** to **An** correlate, ie. have the same sign, with the time serie **O** with a probability **p1** to **pn**.

Let's says that we know the last realisation of **A1** to **An** what would be the best way to predict **O** ? I'm thinking of selecting the time series that have a correlation factor **p>0.55** and do some kind of linear combination. Maybe you could point in some direction to get the optimal predictor.

Comment: There can be no general answer to the question as you stated it, because it will depend on the correlation of the predictors $A_{1:n}$ with **each other**. Do you have training data? Or just $p_{1:n}$ and the last realization of $A_{1:n}$?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 yes I have access to the historical data, so I would have to work out the correlation matrix for the $A_{1:n}$ but what would I do with it ?

Comment: I was using "correlation" in an informal way, as your question did. If you have training data, then a standard approach* would be [logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/logistic/info). (*"standard" in the case where you are only using the most recent $A_{1:n}$, i.e. not really a *time-series* approach, which would use history.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for the [*Naive Bayes* classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier). It assumes that given the output $O$ the input time series $A$ are independent. Now to predict $O$ from $A_i$ we have:

$$
\begin{split}
p(O | A_1 \dots A_n) 
&= \frac{p(A_1 \dots A_n|O) \times p(O)}{p(A_i \dots A_n)} \\
&= \frac{p(A_1|O)\times \dots \times p(A_n|O) \times p(O)}{p(A_i \times \dots \times A_n)} \\
&= \frac{p(A_1|O)\times \dots \times p(A_n|O) \times p(O)}{p(A_i \times \dots \times A_n|O = +) + p(A_i \times \dots \times A_n|O = -)} \\
&\sim p(A_1|O)\times \dots \times p(A_n|O) \times p(O) \\
p(A_i|O) &= \frac{\sum_j A_i^j\times O^j}{\sum_j O^j}  \\
p(O) &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_j O^j \\
\end{split}
$$

Note that for a naive Bayes classifier you do not have to assume that the time series are independent. They should only be independent conditioned on the output variable.

Naive Bayes is a well-known and often used method and implemented in almost any statistical tool you can think of.

Comment: So let's say that $A_1 = +1, A_2 = +1, A_3 = -1$  and  $p_1 = 0.6, p_2 = 0.52, p_3 = 0.57, p_O = 0.5$ (probability of O being +1) then the probability of O settling to + for the last realisation would be : $0.6 \times 0.52 \times 0.43 \times 0.5$ ? I'm not sure about the $0.43$, also why $p(A_i \times \dots \times A_n)$ is considered to be close to 1 ? Thanks

Comment: I am assuming that $A_1 \dots A_n$ are all seperate timeseries, thus $A_1 = \{+, +, -, +, \dots\}$ and $A_2 = \{-, +, -, \dots \}$, etc.

Comment: The correct answer would be $p(O=+) = \frac{0.6 \times 0.52 \times (1-0.57) \times 0.5}{0.6 \times 0.52 \times (1-0.57) \times 0.5 + (1-0.6) \times (1-0.52) \times 0.57 \times (1-0.5)}$.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{1}{N} \sum_j A_i^j\times O^j=p(A_i,O)$? i.e. the *joint* probability? Whereas $p(A_i|O)=\frac{\sum_j A_i^j\times O^j}{\sum_j O^j}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I've changed it.